# Extracting Text from line

Tags: bash

I need help extracting certain part of line from file.

Here is how my file looks like:

```
testfile.txt
This is a test line 1 $#%#
This is a test line 2 $#%#
This is a test line 3 $#%#
This is a test line 4 $#%#
This is a test line 5 $#%#
This is a test line 6 $#%#
This is a test line 7 $#%#
```

and here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
#echo $line
FilterString=${line:22:26}
echo $FilterString>>testfile2.txt
done<testfile.txt
```

The above script gets the string `$#%#` and writes to temp file

My Question:

Instead of writing the string `$#%#` i want everything except string `$#%#` written to file.
So i want my final output file to look like:

```
testfile.txt
This is a test line 1 
This is a test line 2 
This is a test line 3 
This is a test line 4 
This is a test line 5 
This is a test line 6 
This is a test line 7
```

Please also suggest me the best tool for doing it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By saying:

```
FilterString=${line:22:26}
```

you *chose* to print the `$#%#` parts of the line.

You could have said:

```
FilterString=${line:0:21}
```

to print the *desired* portion of the line.  Alternatively, you could say:

```
FilterString=${line//\$#%#/}
```

(note that the `$` sign needs to be escaped)

---

Using `sed`, you could have said:

```
sed 's/ $#.*//g' testfile.txt
```

Supplying the `-i` option to `sed` would make the changes *in-place*:

```
sed -i 's/ $#.*//g' testfile.txt
```

---

As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630838/extracting-text-from-line/19630952#comment29144659_19630862), if you want to remove text from *fixed positions* in the file, using `cut` might simplify things.  Saying:

```
cut -b1-21,27- testfile.txt
```

would remove bytes `22-26` (inclusive) from all lines in the file `testfile.txt`.

Answer (score 5):

If it is just the last field you want to delete, you can use `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NF=NF-1' file
This is a test line 1
This is a test line 2
This is a test line 3
This is a test line 4
This is a test line 5
This is a test line 6
This is a test line 7
```

It decreases in one the number of fields, so that the last one is not taken into consideration.

Then, it performs the default action of `awk` that is `{print $0}`.

To redirect to a file, use `awk 'NF=NF-1' file > new_file`.

---

### Update

As per your comment

> In my case it will not always be the last field, it might also be in
>   between the other fields however at predefined position(always fixed
>   position).

Then you can use the following `awk` syntax:

```
awk -v c=col_num '{$(c)=""}1' file
```

where `col_num` can be set manually like:

```
$ awk -v c=3 '{$(c)=""}1' file
This is  test line 1 $#%#
This is  test line 2 $#%#
This is  test line 3 $#%#
This is  test line 4 $#%#
This is  test line 5 $#%#
This is  test line 6 $#%#
This is  test line 7 $#%#
$ awk -v c=5 '{$(c)=""}1' file
This is a test  1 $#%#
This is a test  2 $#%#
This is a test  3 $#%#
This is a test  4 $#%#
This is a test  5 $#%#
This is a test  6 $#%#
This is a test  7 $#%#
```

You can also use `cut` like this, omitting the field you want to skip:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f1,2,3,4,5,6 file
This is a test line 1
This is a test line 2
This is a test line 3
This is a test line 4
This is a test line 5
This is a test line 6
This is a test line 7

$ cut -d' ' -f1,2,3,5,6,7 file
This is a line 1 $#%#
This is a line 2 $#%#
This is a line 3 $#%#
This is a line 4 $#%#
This is a line 5 $#%#
This is a line 6 $#%#
This is a line 7 $#%#
```

Comment: In my case it will not always be the last field, it might also be in between the other fields however at predefined position(always fixed position)

Comment: OK @Rockwire then you can play with column name. In 5 min I will update, something like `awk -vcol=$col '$(col)=""' file`, being `$col` a bash var, should make it.

Answer (score 1):

> `Instead of writing the string "$#%#" i want everything except string "$#%#" written to file.`

It can be done using sed inline:

```
sed -i.bak 's/ *\$#%#//g' testfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close:

```
FilterString=${line:0:22}
```

Or to just filter the garbage:

```
FilterString=${line% \$#%#}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line
do
#echo $line
FilterString=`python -c "s='$line';print s[:s.find('$')]"`
echo $FilterString>>testfile2.txt`
```

This sample can work with various lenth. For example with file context:

```
...
This is a test line 6 $#%#
This is a test line 1024 $#%#
...
```

you will get next result:

```
This is a test line 6
This is a test line 1024
```

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate all your answers guys:

Will use script based on @devnull's answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
#echo $line
#FilterString=${line:22:26}
echo $line | cut -b1-20,27- >>testfile2.txt
done<testfile
```

therefore if the file look like

```
testfile.txt
This is a test line 1 $#%# more text
This is a test line 2 $#%# more text
This is a test line 3 $#%# more text
This is a test line 4 $#%# more text
This is a test line 5 $#%# more text
This is a test line 6 $#%# more text
This is a test line 7 $#%# more text
```

then output will be:

```
testfile2.txt
This is a test line  more text
This is a test line  more text
This is a test line  more text
This is a test line  more text
This is a test line  more text
This is a test line  more text
This is a test line  more text
```

which is exactly what i wanted